# Am I using the scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline `integral` function correctly?

Tags: python, scipy

I am running python `3.10.4` with scipy `1.8.1` and want to use the `interpolate.RectBivariateSpline` class as it is the only one with an integral function over non-integer areas.

As I understand it correctly, given a 2D-matrix with a regular grid the `RectBivariateSpline` class is the fastest with integral ability out-of-the-box. So in order to test the functionality, here is my code:

```py
matrix = scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(
    np.arange(0, 1000, 1),
    np.arange(0, 1000, 1),
    np.ones((1000, 1000)),
    kx=1,
    ky=1,
)

print(matrix.integral(0, 0, 999, 999))
```

and here is the output: `0.0`.

With a matrix of shape `(1000, 1000)` of constant value `1.0`, the output of the integral over the full matrix should be 1 million, right?

On a sidenote, maybe this would also be a good candidate for an issue on the github page?

Comment: Just a typo: the call signature for `.integral` is `integral(xa, xb, ya, yb)`

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much. I was really confused, that it did (not) work. However with the given input of mine, it also works, haha!